# Accessing the "security.csrf.token_manager" service directly from the container is deprecated, use dependency injection instead

Tags: php, symfony

I upgraded Symfony to 5.2, and I got some deprecation notices:

> Since symfony/framework-bundle 5.2: Accessing the "security.csrf.token_manager" service directly from the container is deprecated, use dependency injection instead.

Here is the relevant code :

```
$client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/fr/mon');
        $csrfToken = $client->getContainer()->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('task_item');
(...)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `static::getContainer()->get()`from KernelTestCase

```php
    public function testYourController()
    {
        //(...)
        $csrfToken = static::getContainer()->get(CsrfTokenManagerInterface::class)->getToken('task_item');
        //(...)
    }
```

Or use `setUp` to call it before each test

```php
//(...)
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
//(...)

    protected $securityCsrf;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->securityCsrf = static::getContainer()->get(CsrfTokenManagerInterface::class);
    }

    public function testYourController()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/fr/mon');
        $csrfToken = $this->securityCsrf->getToken('task_item');
        //(...)
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should getting a service in the `setUp` method work different?

Comment: @NicoHaase You are right. I edited my post to make it a little clearer. When I saw `static::createClient();` in the question, I thought directly to the tests.

Comment: Please add more details - you still haven't explained **why** your code works different. It still fetches a service directly from the container, shouldn't that throw the same deprecation notice than in the question?

Comment: In the question, `getContainer` comes from KernelBrowser. In my case, I use `getContainer` from KernelTestCase which uses dependency injection. In Symfony docs: [Retrieving Services in the Test](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#retrieving-services-in-the-test)

Comment: "which uses dependency injection" - that sounds strange. The linked documentation clearly states that the container is nearly the same container (where private services are accessible), and all such containers in Symfony use dependency injection

Comment: I'm trying to understand. When I try `$client->getContainer()` instead of `static::getContainer()`, I have a different deprecation than the question: _Using the "Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStorage" without a session has no effect and is deprecated. ..._. So it's not a problem with dependency injection in my case but I'm on Symfony 5.4. In any case, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use autowiring https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#an-autowiring-example

```
private CsrfTokenManagerInterface $tokenManager;

public function __construct(
    CsrfTokenManagerInterface $tokenManager
) {
    $this->tokenManager = $tokenManager;
}

...

$csrfToken = $this->tokenManager->getToken('task_item');
```

Comment: Please share more details. How does this work in a test class that is not registered as a service?

Answer (score -2):

Finally, I found the way :

```
$extract = $this->crawler->filter('input[name="mytable[_token]"]')
->extract(array('value'));
$csrf_token = $extract[0];
```